# Tomcat Logging With Slf4j and Log4j

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, slf4j

I've got a web-app deployed to a `Tomcat 7` server.  My application uses `log4j` and a `file appender`.  However, not all logging messages are getting written to the file.

On my classpath, I have:

```
log4j-1.2.14.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
```

My `log4j.properties` file is working fine on my local machine and is deploy properly.

I see application generated error messages being written to `catalina.out` that are not getting written to my `log4j log`.  The log messages in `catalina.out` look to be coming from some other logging framework because the output pattern is in a different format than my `log4j` pattern.  The logging that I'm seeing in the `catalina.log` is like:

```
Nov 4, 2011 11:05:31 AM org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.StateUtils reconstruct
SEVERE
```

And my log4j pattern is like:

```
2011-11-03 16:42:09,336 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-13] ERROR
```

Some logging appears in my `log4j` file log, but not all of it.  From what I've read, `slf4j` just needs those jars for it to funnel log output.  Any ideas?

Comment: You might try using the slf4j jar named "log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.1.jar" instead of the log4j jar named "log4j-1.2.14.jar"

Comment: log4j-over-slf4j.jar is a log4j replacement. The asker does not want to replace log4j. DwB, I suggest that you delete your comment as it is misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try including the jcl-over-slf4j as a dependency. myfaces is probably using commons-logging.

check the slf4j docs: http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#jcl-over-slf4j

Comment: ah, not commons-logging but even java util logging, see ceki's answer

Answer (score 13):

It looks like the [StateUtils](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/myfaces/core/trunk/shared/src/main/java/org/apache/myfaces/shared/util/StateUtils.java?revision=1188235&view=markup) class is using java.util.logging (jul). It stands to reason that other myfaces classes also use jul. Thus, you would probably want to funnel jul logs through SLF4J. Have a look at [bridging legacy APIs](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html), in particular the `jul-to-slf4j` bridge.

Please see [SLF4JBridgeHandler javadocs](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/bridge/SLF4JBridgeHandler.html) for usage instructions when installing `jul-to-slf4j`.

Comment: I tried including both jul-to-slf4j & jcl-over-slf4j dependencies one at a time & another time both together but nothing happened, Still can't see logs by myfaces. The logs from rest of my application are successfully routed to logback via SL4J & written both to file & to netbeans console but cannot see myfaces logs. Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Please see SLF4JBridgeHandler javadocs for usage instructions when installing jul-to-slf4j.

Comment: Thanks as per your suggestion I tried after installing SLF4JBridgeHandler properly & it worked! However using a more performant approach using `LevelChangePropagator` didn't worked out. However that's a different issue. Thanks anyways. In 1st case,I got 2 messages for each log (ie, like this:) `INFO  j.e.s.s.c.s.e.server.logging -> INFO  o.a.m.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger -> No context init parameter ... found.`  
`INFO  o.a.m.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger -> No context init parameter ... found`

Comment: Also could you explain why didn't Myfaces allowed the flexibility to  plug in your desired logging implementation instead of using JUL/  Commons logging ?!

Comment: "why" questions can only be answered by the Myfaces designers themselves. Note that commons-logging is quite old, I would rather ask framework designers to actually use SLF4J.

Answer (score 2):

Configure your tomcat server according to the steps described at http://adfinmunich.blogspot.de/2012/03/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-use-slf4j.html. This blog entry describes how to replace java.util.logging by slf4j (using log4j behind the facade).