# How to configure Myfaces to log through logback

Tags: jsf, logging, jsf-2, myfaces

How do I configure Myfaces to write to the logs through logback implementation which rest of my application uses ? Currently I'm writing logs from all parts of my application except the messages by Myfaces in log files.

I can find the messages from Myfaces even in the netbeans console.

---

Using Myfaces 2.1.8 with Glassfish 3.1 (Netbeans)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Myfaces may be logging to JUL. So you may be required to use `jul-to-slf4j` to redirect all logging to SLF4J.

Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012595/tomcat-logging-with-slf4j-and-log4j) for how to fix.