# SLF4j logs are not printing from the Jar file

Tags: jar, log4j, slf4j

I have created a sample java project which contains servlets and servlet code is having log entries to print the log messages. I am using SLF$j to print the logs in the servlets. This entire project is made as a "sampleProject.jar" files with no manifest.mf file. I am using this jar file in other project which runs on a tomcat(Web-application). If i run this
web-application from tomcat which contains "sampleProject.jar". I am not able to see the log messages which i have written in the servet code(from jar) but the application is working as expected without printing the logs. 
By above setup i could not be able to see the logs printed, that's why i created the log4j.properties file with appenders as console and file and placed the binding libraries(log4j.jar, slf4j-logfj12.jar) along with the slf4j. Now i created the jar file again with the additional changes.Now also i could not be able to print the logs, i am getting the following error in the console.

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Please guide if i am doing wrong by looking at the above explanation.

Am i creating a sampleProject.jar incorrectly?
Why i am getting the the above error even i placed the required bindings?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have one of these files on your classpath *slf4j-nop.jar, slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or logback-classic.jar*?

Please read the SLF4J documentation: http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder

> Failed to load class org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
>
> This error is reported when the org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
> class could not be loaded into memory. This happens when no
> appropriate SLF4J binding could be found on the class path. Placing
> one (and only one) of slf4j-nop.jar, slf4j-simple.jar,
> slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or logback-classic.jar on the class
> path should solve the problem.
>
> SINCE 1.6.0 As of SLF4J version 1.6, in
> the absence of a binding, SLF4J will default to a no-operation (NOP)
> logger implementation.
>
> You can download SLF4J bindings from the
> project download page.

Comment: Hello @Bruno, I am adding required bindings in the classpath of jar file, I have also mentioned that in above explanation.

Comment: Hi @M.S.Naidu, sorry, I haven't read your entire post. Check your tomcat classpath. Copying all your dependencies into TOMCAT_HOME/lib could fix it. This blog post could also help you: http://adfinmunich.blogspot.de/2012/03/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-use-slf4j.html

Comment: Some good answers that might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012595/tomcat-logging-with-slf4j-and-log4j